# Trigger a function based on two different selectors jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

JavaScript here is suppose to trigger these functions based on two different selectors. Not sure how to use the selectors though. I need to differentiate between slideLeft and slideRight based on selectors with the same name.

The javascript is below

```
function slideRight($el){
    $el.css('marginLeft', '-70px').animate({marginLeft: '+=70px'},{ duration: 500, queue: false }).fadeIn(500, false).removeClass('hidden');
}

function slideLeft($el){
    $el.css('marginright', '-70px').animate({marginright: '+=70px'},{ duration: 500, queue: false }).fadeIn(500, false).removeClass('hidden');
}

function checkAudioCue(){
    try {
        var num = Math.floor(curTime);
        var entryNum;
        if(audioCues[""+num]){
            entryNum = audioCues[""+num];
        }

        if (entryNum != undefined){
            var $el = $('.hidden[data-cuenum="' + entryNum + '"]');
            /*$('.hidden[data-cuenum="' + entryNum + '"]').removeClass('hidden'); */
            slideRight($el);
        }
    } catch(error){}
}
```

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="hidden slideRight" data-cuenum="2">
    <h4>TEXT</h4>
    <div class="hidden slideRight" data-cuenum="3">
        <p><strong>Text:</strong> Text</p>
        <span class="color2">
            <ul>
                <li>Text </li>
            </ul>
        </span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use another parameter for your function:

```
function slide($el, dir){
    var prop = 'margin'+dir.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+dir.slice(1),
        anim = {};
    anim[prop] = '+=70px';
    $el.removeClass('hidden')
       .css(prop, '-70px')
       .animate(anim, { duration: 500, queue: false })
       .fadeIn(500, false);
}
```

```
slide($('.hidden[data-cuenum="' + entryNum + '"]'), "right");
```